# How to start an NSTimer when i click on a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, nstimer

How can i start an NSTimer when a user clicks a button?

EDIT:i had the code working and everything, but i put the code to hide the button above the NSTimer code, and when i placed it below the NSTimer code it worked!

Answer (score 9):

The line of code to start a timer is ([read the docs here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-CHDDAEIA)) :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:nil];
```

This will call the method `timerFired:` after 1 second i.e.

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
  NSLog(@"timer : %@ has gone off", timer);
}
```

To get this to trigger from a button, you need this method in your .h file :

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

and in your .m file, detect the button press like this :

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"Button's been pressed!");
}
```

Then, in interface builder connect the button's 'Toiuch Up Inside' action to this method.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule it in the IBAction of the button. Check [NSTimer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to know how to use timers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the command of`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:nil];`
inside the buttonclick. Then only you could make the NStimer run after the button click (if you want to run the timer after the button click event )